# JSF 2.0 Ajax Exception Handling

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I have written the following code in our xhtml file , for redirecting to error page for ajax calls, I have written it in common page.

```
var onError = function onError() {
window.location = 'http://' + jQuery(location).attr('host')+'/saec/app/error';//saec/app/error };jsf.ajax.addOnError(onError);
```

It is working fine fine , but in browser am getting the error as "Jsf undefined".

I have tried it by including the

```
h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces" target="head"
```

also but its giving the same error.

Can any one Please tell me where I did the mistake

Answer (score 2):

> *but in browser am getting the error as "Jsf undefined".*

Are you sure that this isn't a typo from your side? It's `jsf` in all lowercase, not `Jsf`.

In any case, you will get this error whenever you try to reference the `jsf` object *before* it is ever been declared in JavaScript context. For example, when the generated HTML output (as you can see by *View Source* in webbrowser) look like this:

```
<script>jsf.ajax.addOnError(functionName);</script>
<script src="/contextname/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces"></script>
```

You should make sure that you reference it *after* it is been declared:

```
<script src="/contextname/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces"></script>
<script>jsf.ajax.addOnError(functionName);</script>
```

Also, you need to take into account the fact that JSF will only auto-include it whenever there's a `<f:ajax>` tag elsewhere in the view. You might want to add an extra check if this is the case or not:

```
if (typeof jsf !== 'undefined') {
    jsf.ajax.addOnError(functionName);
}
```

Otherwise, you need to add the following line to make absolutely sure that JSF will auto-include the ajax script on every request even though the view doesn't contain any `<f:ajax>`.

```
<h:outputScript library="javax.faces" name="jsf.js" target="head" />
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, if you'd like to use the standard `<error-page>` mechanisms in `web.xml` on ajax requests as well, then consider using this [`FullAjaxExceptionHandler`](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2012/03/full-ajax-exception-handler.html) instead.